# An anime from the 70's or 80's which had a scene of a large guy gunning down teddy bears

Tags: space-firebird-2772

The anime was from the 1970's or the very early 1980's. I really don't have much to go on, I'm afraid, but it was Sci-Fi, and I'm pretty sure it had robots in it as well as humanoid characters. They were on a journey/quest, and, this may be the best clue, there was a disturbing scene (remember, I was young!) where a large guy with a beard or mustache was gunning down teddy bears (or cute bears of some kind) in a room with what looked like an M60 machine gun.

This has been driving me NUTS! Please, if anyone can help, I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: The only thing I can think of offhand is [Pierrot le Fou](http://cowboybebop.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_Pierrot) from Cowboy Bebop, who shoots up stuffed cats, but that show's from 1998...

Answer (score 5):

It's **[Space Firebird 2772](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2793/Hi_no_Tori_2772:_Ai_no_CosmoZone)** (1980). That scene made a big impression on me as a kid too! Great movie, worth re-watching as an adult.

The scene is around 15 minutes into the movie:

[image: The gunning scene] [image: The large guy with a beard and mustache]

Comment: Could you post a screenshot or indicate the time of the gunning down teddy bears scene? I couldn't seem to find it in *Space Firebird 2772*.

Comment: The English clip of that bit of the film doesn't seem to be working on YouTube, it's around 15 mins in, you can see it in German here http://youtu.be/2XPQnkTKVBw

Comment: @STP: might you elaborate on your answer and give a few more reasons why you think this is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: Early 80s? Check.

Sci Fi? Check.

Robots/humanoids? Check. 

Journey/quest? Check.

Exact scene OP described? Yep, that's there too.

What is it with you guys? At this stage I've posted a link to the whole movie so the OP can see if I'm right when he comes back on here. You know I just chanced upon the question and thought I'd help the guy out since I know the answer. Go watch the film.

Comment: @STP Links don't count for anything here on Stack Exchange. Links go dead all the time. Maroon is just asking that you edit your answer to include additional facts that will help collaborate it, like those you mentioned in your comment. Remember your answer is meant to help not just original poster but anyone else with a similar question.

Comment: No, my answer was intended only to answer the original, very specific question asked. That was my intention. The OP wanted to know what the movie was, I recognised it from his description and supplied him with the name. Should he see my first post he will find either that his question has been answered correctly, or that I am wrong (I'm not). The name of the film is sufficient information for him to do so.
No corroboration (not collaboration) was necessary. If you or anyone else is in doubt as to the validity of my claim, I suggest you investigate it yourselves and prove me wrong.

Comment: Oh My God!! @STP, you have seriously made my day, and gone above and beyond the call of duty :)  I cannot begin to tell you how grateful I am for the answer. As far as corroboration, let me assure you guys that he has hit the nail on the head. I never hoped that someone could identify it from my somewhat vague question, but he really has got it in one!  Thanks everyone for taking the time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: More than welcome mate!

Comment: @STP You're misunderstanding the purpose of the site. Good answers help more than just person asking the question, and so good answers shouldn't restrict themselves to just the bare minimum necessary to satisfy the original poster. That's why links aren't valued much, once they go dead it can't help anyone else.

Comment: I don't misunderstand, I just don't care. This is not school; There's no obligation to show the workings of my answer. The guy who asked the question is happy and whether or not some geeks who didn't ask the question nor know the answer consider my answer a good one is irrelevant.
Did you ask the question? No. Did you know the answer? No. So what has any of this got to do with you? Nothing at all. As it stands the question and answer, without links, would be useful for someone looking for the same movie but regardless of this, some of you nerds need to get a life.